# Is there a way to change the width of the line of a ggplot for a certain x-value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the code I am using to create a ggplot for the COVID mortality. Each year has a different colour but we also have to make the line thicker in the years 2020 and 2021 but I don't know how to change this specific part of the line. I tried looking it up but all I could find was how to change the width of a full line, not a specific part of it. Anybody any suggestions?

[image]

```
ggplot(data = preds, 
       aes(x=DATE, y=1E7*PER_CAPITA_MORTALITY)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=factor(YEAR), size = 0.01)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=1E7*PER_CAPITA_MORTALITY), colour="black", size=0.3) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=baseline.lower.CI, ymax=baseline.upper.CI), fill="steelblue", 
              colour=NA, alpha=I(0.4)) + # 95% confidence intervals (dark grey)
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=baseline.lower.PI, ymax=baseline.upper.PI), fill="steelblue", 
              colour=NA, alpha=I(0.2)) +
  ggtitle("PREDICTED MORTALITY IN BELGIUM PER 10M PER WEEK)",
          subtitle="dark and light shaded areas = 95% confidence and prediction intervals") +
  xlab("YEAR") + ylab("Predicted mortality (per 10M per week)") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 20) +
  facet_wrap(~ model)
```

Comment: Add `linewidth = DATE` within `aes()` to the geom that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `if_else` on the `year` combined with `linewidth` (I've used some made-up data in `data_df` to demonstrate):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data_df <- tribble(~date, ~value,
        "2019-01-01", 1,
        "2019-04-01", 2,
        "2019-07-01", 3,
        "2019-10-01", 1,
        "2020-01-01", 1,
        "2020-04-01", 4,
        "2020-07-01", 5,
        "2020-10-01", 2,
        "2021-01-01", 2,
        "2021-04-01", 4,
        "2021-07-01", 5,
        "2021-10-01", 2,
        "2022-01-01", 1,
        "2022-04-01", 2,
        "2022-07-01", 3,
        "2022-10-01", 1) |> 
  mutate(date = ymd(date),
         year = year(date))

data_df |> 
  ggplot(aes(date, value)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = if_else(data_df$year %in% c("2020", "2021"), 3, 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>